VSCode "Failed to delete used the Recycle Bin" and Issue renaming files
I ended up here because I've been told to ask my question here. Trying to ask a question on VSCode's Git redirect to StackOverflow, and they themselves redirected me here.

When I try to delete a folder from VSCode directly, it sometimes asks me to execute the action as an administrator, then show an error "Failed to delete used the Recycle Bin". Only thing that I can do is to remove it permanently. I even tried to set all permissions of the folder to "total control" for the system and users, but that changed nothing.

Video (Delete issue): https://streamable.com/vawgm5

Kind of same issue happens when I try to rename a file. VSCode is just stuck in a loading loop and never updates, it eventually crashes. I'm forced to close it and re-open it again to see the modification.

Video (Rename issue): https://streamable.com/ljez2q

Note that all these files are stored in local, on my laptop's disk. There is no server, SSH request or something like that in the equation. Just a regular use. Also:

No opened program is currently using the project.
The project isn't Git-ed.
It is not opened in the files explorer either (I prefer to mention it as in the video, it is open but on another folder). I even tried with the files explorer completely closed.
I wondered if it wasn't something in my system. But apparently not as I changed my laptop recently, and I still have the same problem on new projects on my new computer.


OS: Windows 11 - 22H3 - 22631.4460
VSCode info:

Version: 1.95.3 (user setup)
Commit: f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813
Date: 2024-11-13T14:50:04.152Z
Electron: 32.2.1
ElectronBuildId: 10427718
Chromium: 128.0.6613.186
Node.js: 20.18.0
V8: 12.8.374.38-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631


So does it happen when you launch VS Code as an Administrator?

Did you disable UAC? When you try and respond to the action, it never appears, which suggests it’s disabled

Hi, yup I already tried to start it as an Administrator, when I try to delete then it just skips the pop-up telling me that it requires an admin profile, but still shows the one saying it is impossible to reach the recycle bin and ask me if I want to delete it permanently.
Same thing happens if I deactivate UAC.

Stop disabling UAC. You can’t actually fully disable UAC on Windows 10+ anyways. So you launch VS Code as an Administrator, does it still prompt you to elevate your permissions, when you do those actions? I cannot reproduce the behavior on my install the suggests something unique about your setup

I mean, it doesn't ask for adminstrator permissions anymore when I run it as an administrator, but it still doesn't manage to reach the recycle bin : https://streamable.com/7lhkmz

Because you hit cancel instead of confirming the action (delete permanently)

What ? The whole issue is about the fact it doesn't manage to reach the recycle bin. Deleting it permanently isn't my goal. Sometimes I can delete folder and they go in the bin without showing this message, but here it especially doesn't work, asking me to delete it permanently instead. This is what I'm trying to fix.

It’s asking you if you would like to delete it, it’s only asking if you would like to permanently delete it, and you canceled the deletion.

I finally found out it was due to an extension I used (in my specific case, Spyglass).
I will continue on their own GitHub.
